# Oracle Function - returns the line of code throws error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I know

```
DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE
```

will return the line number , where the error occurred.

is there any way to get the actual code statement which give the error in Oracle 11g?

Comment: Only by looking at the source code, e.g in `user_source`. Exposing the source code would be an odd thing to do though.

Comment: Hey.. Alex. Thank you !!! 
I was just checking .. because , we don't have access to see the code, cause its in different database, Every time we are depend on other team, cause multiple packages needs to be verified, If there is such option to get the exact piece of code which throws error, That would have been very helpful. But anyways nothing can be down as of now :) 
Thanks Again.. You are helpful as always :)

Comment: @AlexPoole by the way, why don't yopu post it as an answer? questioner would mark it as done and there will be clear it is already answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a similar mechanism to get the source code automatically.

You could, in principal, get the source code for that line (and maybe surrounding lines) from the `user_source` or `all_source` data dictionary views.

The scenario you've described, though, is that you don't have access to the source on the database that is throwing the initial exception. The calling PL/SQL block that currently catches and formats the exception can only see the remote source if the database link user has been granted privileges to see the code in that database, and you've implied it doesn't. You can verify by querying `all_source@db_link` for the owner and package/procedure in the stack trace. And always try asking for it if you don't ave it already - the source may well not be public on purpose, of course.

If you did have that access you could look at the source manually over that link. You could also query that within your local exception handler, and - as a debugging tool - output that, say with `dbms_output`. That's then no different to looking at local code, you just have the DB link in the query. But exposing that remote code to whoever calls your local procedure might not be sensible.